# Как установить joomla 2.5.1 на postgresql ?

Tags: установка, joomla, postgresql

**Как установить joomla 2.5.1 на postgresql ?**

Пробую на alwaysdata.com и у себя локале и не выходит, **джумла не определяет postgresql**

в php,ini раскоментировал postgres

Comment: буду благодарен если кто поможет...

Comment: А вы уверены, что постгрес работает?

Comment: ДА, я уверен

Comment: Т. е. phpPgAdmin позволяет создать БД?
А простое раскомментирование строчки не является залогом того, что модуль заработал, его с начала надо установить XD

Answer (score 3):

А кто сказал, что Joomla поддерживает PostgreSQL: http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html

Comment: Теперь поддерживает однако, спасибо:)